# Vue.js function is always being called for a bound class

Tags: javascript, class, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a button like that

```
                 <button
                    @click="
                        SOMETHING
                    "
                    class="base-button-green base-big-btn"
                    :class="googleTag('asd')"
                >
                    {{ $t("start.tryFree") }}
                </button>
```

And my function is:

```
googleTag(a) {
        console.log("googleTag");
        return "dummyGoogle";
    }
```

This function is always being called. I see in the console 100s of times this log.
Why this happens and how can I prevent that?

Comment: At first look, you are calling the function `googleTag()`, which causes the component to rerender. When it is rerendered, you are calling it again and it goes to an infinite loop.

Comment: I understand but how can ı prevent this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Binding the an attribute to a method causes infinite rendering, any attribute should be bound to a property (data or computed) :

```
        <button
                @click="
                    SOMETHING
                "
                class="base-button-green base-big-btn"
                class="googleTag"
            >
                {{ $t("start.tryFree") }}
            </button>
```

computed property

```
computed:{
   googleTag(){
       return "dummyGoogle";
   }


}
```

Note that the method are used event handlers and they shouldn't be bound to an attribute or interpolated

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works. What I want to do is there are lots of components that I need to use like that and they need to have different class names how can I achieve this?.

Comment: you could use an array like `return ['dummyGoogle','otherclass']`